# Error using \lrtimes

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am trying to use a symbol mapped by the tag `\lrtimes` in Math mode, but I am getting error. Here is what I am doing.

```
\begin{align*}
Sys_1 \stackrel{\text{\tiny def}}{=} (Appl \parallel Appl) \lrtimes  WS
\end{align*}
```

The `\stackrel{\text{\tiny def}}{=}` is a latex code for 'is defined as' operator which works fine in my other formulas.

The log message(from texmaker) reads as below:

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>    ...}{=} (Appl \parallel Appl) \lrtimes
>   WS
>   l.69 \end{align*}
>   The control sequence at the end of the top line
>   of your error message was never \def'ed.

What is wrong in this case?

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Ya sure, i agree

Comment: the name `\bowtie` also represents the same symbol, and it's already present in latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `\lrtimes` you need `\usepackage{pxfonts}` in the preamble:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
Sys_1 \stackrel{\text{\tiny def}}{=} (Appl \parallel Appl) \lrtimes  WS
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The reason for the error is that pxfonts.sty file is missing.

Comment: One should note that this globally changes the document font.